# Ubuntu touch app store

Tags: ubuntu-touch, click-packages

I have uploaded my apps in the Ubuntu touch app store.I have uploaded the ARM version of it.If I want it to be available on amd64 or i386 do I also have to upload the other 2 versions?(I know stupid question,but I feel nervous about it,I don't want to get banned from the store)

Also when unity 8 becomes the default for desktop Ubuntu,will users be able to download my apps on their desktop pc's?

Answer (score 2):

Only upload the *armhf* build to the store for now, if your app requires native code. In the future, it will be possible to have *armhf*, *i386*, and any other supported architecture, included in the same package. Support for that has been deprioritized a bit though, as development is currently concentrated on the phone platform.

It's already possible to install apps from the store on a PC, when running the *Ubuntu Desktop Next* preview image.

Comment: thing is desktop next is not working on my laptop :(